# Anyway to set/fix the IP address of a Minikube cluster using KVM

Tags: minikube, kvm

I would like to have a fixed IP address for the minikube cluster (the one obtained when typing minikube ip) on my ubuntu host machine (with KVM2) on every start and stop.

I would like to point a DNS subdomain to it in order to test some security stuffs based on subdomain certificates.

is there any way to have that?

Comment: did you find any other workaround?

Comment: unfortunately not. I need to point the subdomain to the new IP address every time it changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently minikube does not support assigning a static IP to the cluster.

There's a feature request for it on K8s Github: [#951 Support for Predictable IP's Across Restarts](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/951).
You can follow it to check it's development.

Also, you can try with the virtualbox driver:`--vm-driver=virtualbox`

It won't assign a static IP but it will maintain the IP when your minikube restarts, so it could help.

Comment: this answer is gold.

Comment: it seems you can now set a static ip for Docker and Podman drivers: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/static_ip/